# Create a list based on groups from a csv file and pass on to SQL query using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am a beginner python user, and would like to run a SQL query, iteratively, on items in a csv file that have the same group.

My input file looks like this:

```
"num","fruit_id","fruit"
1,1000560,"apple"
1,1102527,"banana"
1,1103314,"orange"
1,1136980,"pineapple"
2,1321636,"cantalope"
2,1506270,"mandarin"
3,1539403,"grape"
3,1549786,"grapefruit"
3,1734104,"tomato
```

I would like to group all the "fruit_id" items with the same "num" into a comma separated list and supply this list in the WHERE statement of my SQL query. I have over 40,000 groups, so I need to do this iteratively.

I know how to run the SQL query in python, but I am struggling with how to best create this grouping, reference it properly in my SQL query, and do it iteratively.  Any input would be very much appreciated.

My SQL query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM db1.table1
JOIN db1.table2 USING (id)
JOIN db1.table3 ON (concept_id=fruit_concept_id)
JOIN db1.table4 USING (detailed_id)
WHERE fruit_id IN ('list_of_fruit_ids_for_group_in_file') 
GROUP BY fruit_id, fruit_concept_id;
```

The 'list_of_fruit_ids_for_group_in_file' would look like :

1. (1000560, 1102527,1103314,1136980) for group 1
2. (1321636, 1506270) for group 2
3. (1539403,1549786,1734104) for group 3

Comment: Hello ! Instead of SQL you should directly use pandas, Can you give more details on the SQL query that you want to do ?

Comment: @PierreK: Thanks so much for your help! I added the SQL query I will be running

Comment: Can you give also an example of the 'list of fruit_ids for group in file' that you want ?

Comment: @PierreK: add this info, thank you!

Comment: First, please tag your RDBMS (Postgres?, MySQL?, SQLite?) and consider importing your CSV as a new table and run the more efficient `JOIN` instead of lists in `IN` clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('datatest.csv', delimiter =',')

for group in np.unique(df.num): 
    #filter df for just the group
    df_group = df[df.num == group]
    #select fruit_id column and get to a list 
    grouplist = np.unique(df_group.fruit_id)
    print("group num : ",group, "fruits :", grouplist)
```

output :

```
group num :  1 fruits : [1000560 1102527 1103314 1136980]
group num :  2 fruits : [1321636 1506270]
group num :  3 fruits : [1539403 1549786 1734104]
```

it's not comma separated in the python print but it's still a list where you can go through or with a WHERE IN

Thus you could try to include your query inside the for loop :

```
    for group in np.unique(df.num): 
        #filter df for just the group
        df_group = df[df.num == group]
        #select fruit_id column and get to a list 
        grouplist = np.unique(df_group.fruit_id)
        data = SQL QUERY... WHERE .. IN grouplist
```

Comment: Thank you @Pierre K, unfortunately I believe I am getting an error due to the python print of the "grouplist", is there a way to overcome this? Thank you

Comment: I added the following to Pierre's code, and ran my SQL query using In grouplistc, and that did the trick!

 grouplistc=','.join(map(str,grouplist))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better idea: use sets.  It will make your code simpler and faster.

```
create table fruits( 
    num int not null,
    fruit_id int not null,
    fruit varchar(30) not null );
```

Insert each line from your CSV file into the `fruits` table.  Likely there are tools for your DBMS to do that; you shouldn't have to write any Python for it.

Now instead of formulating a WHERE clause, use EXISTS:

```
select count(*) from T
where exists( select 1 from fruits 
              where T.fruit_id = fruit_id and num = 1 )
```

or whatever it is you're after.

It's not obvious you "have to do this iteratively".  It seems at least as likely to me that one query will do the job quicker and easier, depending on capacity and use.

Comment: Thank you, James. Unfortunately, I have over 40,000 groups, so I do need something that can iterate over all of these groups. Is there a way to do that the SQL code you added?